# Write GeoPandas data into osm.pbf file using Python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmosis, pbf

I have sample nodes, edges data like below. I am using `ElementTree` to write the data into `.osm` file and then trying to convert into `.osm.pbf` using osmosis but when trying to convert from `.osm` to `.osm.pbf` osmosis throws error saying `"osm format is not not supported"`. Is my output format wrong? Also, this process is very slow, time-consuming and not cost-efficient.

Is there any library that converts GeoPandas node, edges data into `.osm.pbf`? What is the best way to convert geopandas(nodes, edges) data into `.osm.pbf` file?

nodes data: https://easyupload.io/4vib5
edges: https://easyupload.io/4k9du7

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

def gpd_to_osm(n_gdf,e_gdf):
    root = ET.Element("osm")
    root.set("version", "0.6")
    root.set("generator", "MyNetworkGenerator")

    for i,row in n_gdf.iterrows():
        current_node = ET.SubElement(root, 'node', attrib={
            'id': str(n_gdf.loc[i,'id']),
            'lat': str(n_gdf.loc[i,'lat']),
            'lon': str(n_gdf.loc[i,'lon']),
            'changeset': 'false'})
        root.append(current_node)

    for i,row in e_gdf.iterrows():
        print(e_gdf.loc[i,'u'])
        current_ways = ET.SubElement(root, 'ways', 
            attrib={'u':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'u']),
                    'v':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'v']),
                    'key':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'key']),
                    'access':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'access']), 
                    'area':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'area']), 
                    'bicycle':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'bicycle']),
                    'bridge':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'bridge']), 
                    'busway':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'busway']),
                    'cycleway':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'cycleway']),
                    'est_width':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'est_width']), 
                    'foot':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'foot']), 
                    'footway':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'footway']), 
                    'highway':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'highway']), 
                    'int_ref':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'int_ref']),
                    'junction':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'junction']),
                    'lanes':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'lanes']), 
                    'lit':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'lit']), 
                    'maxspeed':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'maxspeed']), 
                    'motorcar':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'motorcar']), 
                    'motorroad':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'motorroad']),
                    'motor_vehicle':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'motor_vehicle']), 
                    'name':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'name']), 
                    'oneway':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'oneway']), 
                    'overtaking':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'overtaking']), 
                    'path':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'path']),
                    'passing_places':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'passing_places']), 
                    'psv':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'psv']), 
                    'ref':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'ref']), 
                    'service':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'service']),
                    'segregated':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'segregated']), 
                    'sidewalk':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'sidewalk']),
                    'smoothness':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'smoothness']), 
                    'surface':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'surface']), 
                    'tracktype':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'tracktype']), 
                    'tunnel':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'tunnel']), 
                    'width':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'width']), 
                    'timestamp':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'timestamp']), 
                    'version':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'version']), 
                    'tags':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'tags']), 
                    'osm_type':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'osm_type']), 
                    'geometry':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'geometry']), 
                    'length':str(e_gdf.loc[i,'length'])})

        root.append(current_ways)

    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write("mynetwork.osm")
```

Output file:- https://easyupload.io/1z6u3e

Osmosis command and error:

```
osmosis --read-xml file="mynetwork.osm" --write-pbf file="output.osm.pbf"
```

Error:

```
osm format is not supported
```

Comment: I don't think the output osm follows [OSM XML specifications](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML#Example_OSM_XML_file). QGIS didn't load the features.

Comment: What is the correct xml format to write the nodes and edge data? I want to write the sample nodes, edges into xml format that is accepted by osm?

Comment: I have not constructed any OSM XML file so far. At least, a `way` consists of `nd`s for nodes and `tag`s for attributes as in [this example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way#Examples).

Comment: Maybe you have a look at the source code of some OSM editors how they build OSM files. Popular examples are JOSM or iD. Maybe this project helps as well https://github.com/woodpeck/morituri